# PhoneGap - batterystatus called but status undefined

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

Cordova (PhoneGap) - batterystatus-callback is called but according to the logg both status and isplugged are **undefined**

What could be the cause?

```
   onDeviceReady: function() {

    //alert('deviceready!!!!!!!!');
    d.lg('device ready :-)');
    window.addEventListener('batterystatus', app.batteryListener, false);   
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');



},


    batteryListener: function() {

    //alert("batterylistener!");
    console.log("Level: " + status.level + " isPlugged: " + status.isPlugged);

}
```

logcat AndroidStudio

```
 2019-04-05 15:38:36.039 17689-17689/com.phonegap.app D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js: Line 93 : Level: undefined isPlugged: undefined
 2019-04-05 15:38:36.039 17689-17689/com.phonegap.app I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(93)] "Level: undefined isPlugged: undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js (93)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `batterListener` method is missing the `status`.

```
batteryListener: function(status) {
```